# Does using Django "is_superuser" require additional URL?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating an administrative interface/dashboard for a Django 1.7 project.  Instead of creating a new admin application from scratch, I'm trying to use Django's built-in admin site.  I have "root" (superuser) and "reviewer" (non-superuser) staff accounts.  Both accounts are in the default "admin" group.  Both accounts can log in to the admin site but some pages are accessible by both the root and reviewer accounts while access to others is limited to the superuser.  I've created the two following views:

```
# mysite/apps/admin/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff)
def all_admins(request, template):
    return render(request, template)

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def superuser_only(request, template):
    return render(request, template)
```

The problem I'm running into is that if I log is using the reviewer account and click the anchor for the "superuser_only" page, I get the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
      Request URL:  http://localhost:8001/accounts/login/?next=/admin/super/
Using the URLconf defined in conf.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^admin/all_admins/$ [name='all-admins']
^admin/super/$ [name='superuser-only']
The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

Is there something else I need to do to implement this superuser-only view and template so that this error doesn't occur if the reviewer clicks the link?

I followed the [Django docs instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and created my own copies of Django's base.html, base_site.html, and index.html templates in my mysite/apps/admin/templates/admin directory and then added the "all_admins" and "superuser_only" anchors to the bottom of the index.html page.

Here are my files:

```
# part of mysite/mysite/settings.py
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps/admin/templates'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps/admin/templates/admin'),)

# mysite/mysite/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^admin/all_admins/$',
        'apps.admin.views.all_admins',
        {'template': 'all_admins.html'},
        name='all-admins'),

    url(r'^admin/super/$',
        'apps.admin.views.superuser_only',
        {'template': 'superuser_only.html'},
        name='superuser-only'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then user doesn't pass the test django redirects it to the login page.  Defult url for this page is `/accounts/login/`.  Set the [`LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#login-url) setting to the admin's login page:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'admin:login'
```

Or, if you have non-staff users on the site, set the auth urls in the `urls.py`:

```
url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

But this will require you to create several templates (login, logout, change password etc.)

**UPDATE**: If you want to show a message in the login page then you can create the [custom login template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.login_template) for admin.  Add this line to your `urls.py`:

```
admin.site.login_template = 'my_login.html'
```

And then create `my_login.html` template which is extended from `admin/login.html`:

```
{% extends 'admin/login.html' %}

{% block content %}

    {% if user.is_staff %}
        <p class="errornote">You need to be a superuser to access that page.</p>
    {% endif %}

    {{ block.super }}

{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE 2**: If you don't want to change site-wide `LOGIN_URL` or implement auth by including `django.contrib.auth.urls` in your `urls.py` then you can pass `login_url` parameter to the `@user_passes_test` decorator:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser, login_url='/admin/login/')
def superuser_only(request, template):
    return render(request, template)
```

Comment: Good catch.  This actually works in that it prevents the error from being displayed but if I'm logged in as the reviewer and I click the "Superuser Only" link now, nothing happens.  I'd like to at least display a template telling the reviewer that they need to be a superuser to access that page. Maybe I have to pass an "is_superuser" variable from the view to the template and only display links to pages that don't require the viewer to be a superuser?  That would get me around the problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand.  Which file does this go in?  If I put it in a "login.html" file in my mysite/apps/admin/templates/admin directory, I get the error "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" on the "{% extends... %} tag in the login.html file I created.

Comment: You shouldn't create `admin/login.html` template. Create your own template and extend it from `login.html`.  Then configure the `admin.site` to use your template instead of `admin/login.html`.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Nope, this still doesn't work and I'm not sure why.  Also, I'm not sure changing LOGIN_URL as shown is advisable as I use that setting for the non-admin part of the site.  Thanks anyway for your suggestions.

Comment: 1. I tested it and t works just fine.  Show the code and error, please. 2. Instead of changing LOGIN_URL you can use the second option - include 'django.contrib.auth.urls' in your `urls.py`. 3. See the updated answer for the third option.